# May I ask for help deciphering this seal?

Tags: translation, character-identification, seal

I am new to Chinese and this seal fascinates me and makes me want to learn more about this complex language.  I have looked all over the internet with not much luck! I would be very grateful for some direction. Would buying a Seal Dictionary be of help? Thank you in advance for any help, suggestions and comments

[image]

Comment: I  flipped the right side image, But I couldn't tell if the left side image was mirrored so I didn't flip it.

Comment: The blue image  is a stamped version (on the paper) of  whats on the side of the seal. And, yes red image  is a mirror image of the seal itself as it would appear on the paper if stamped. Big thanks to you Tang Ho

Answer (score 2):

Right-hand-side seal

> [image: 取諸懷抱]

「取諸懷抱」

*Indulge in one's deepest thoughts*, a line from the preface of the poem anthology [Lántíng Xù](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lantingji_Xu).

---

Left-hand-side seal: I believe this is

> [image: What?]

```
屮　亾（亡）
　艸
二　中
```

I cannot make sense of this. Maybe 「二屮」 refers to 「艸」 in the middle. This might be a puzzle, or might be nonsense.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I will have to review this poem. This might have some validity I was told;  this seal belonged to a Chinese general who passed away during some war in early 20h century in Manchuria. He gave this seal to a nun that was taking care of him before he passed away. It has been in her European family ever since.

Comment: Thank you so much dROOze!!!

Comment: Just adding some more possibilities: the top-left character of the left-hand-side seal could also be 又, which means 'right hand', judging from the bending at the bottom.

Comment: https://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E5%8F%88

Comment: @BrianCheung if that was a hand, it would be [*left hand* 「」](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=19787) rather than *right hand* 「又」. A *hand* was originally my first guess too - but 「」 and 「又」 usually have the fingers pointing sideways, not upwards.

Comment: @dROOOze ah you have your point! Well, then I guess you are right. It should be a 屮.